# Opencart 2.1 зависает страница модификаторов, бесконечная загрузка

Tags: opencart, браузер

Страница отображается, есть возможность перейти по ссылкам страницы модификаторов в админке, но страница в этот момент загружается и через секунд 10-15 секунд вылазит ошибка страницы «Опаньки произошел сбой гугл хром…». В других браузерах, устройствах такая же ситуация.
Куда копать, что делать, что проверять?

Answer (score 1):

Страница модификаторов имеет свой лог, лог стал огромных размеров, файл так долго обрабатывался сервером, что вызывало тайминг завершения загрузки страницы.